# Get combined code coverage for cucumber-js and mochaJS test cases using NYC

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, cucumber, mocha.js, nyc

In our codebase, we have written acceptance test cases in cucumber-js and unit tests in mocha js. The individual way to run these is by:

Mocha - `"test:mocha-coverage": "nyc npm run test"`

Cucumber - `"test:cucumber-coverage": "nyc npm run test:cucumber"`

Now we want to get a combined code coverage by these two. I have tried running both test cases together inside NYC but that did not work. Has someone done this?